# Pass a constructor argument to a @component class in java

Tags: java, spring, constructor

I am using spring with Java based configuration. I have a component class which needs to have its constructor auto-wired(rather at compile-time).

Here is the component class

```
package com.project.fileservices; 

@Component
public class FileU {

    FileWriter fw_output;

    @Autowired
    public FileU(String s){

    }
}
```

Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.project")
public class ResponseConfig {

@Bean
    public  ResponseTypeService protectionResponse() throws Exception{
        return new ProtectionTypeResponse();
    }   
}
```

Here I need to auto-wire the FileU with Constructed String from Constructor

```
 class ProtectionTypeResponse{
      @Autowired
      FileU filewriter; // i want the constructed(with constructor) FileU object.
    }
```

Comment: There are multiple different ways, it depends on where that String value actually comes from. Is it hardcoded, from a properties file, etc.

Comment: Your autowired argument is not supposed to change in most of the time. Is the string that you're passing to it always constant?

Comment: Actually its from a properties file

Comment: Once it's been passed I do not want to change it at runtime.

Comment: Not answering your question, but since you have a \@Configuration class, why not define your beans in there with \@Bean and remove all the \@Autowired and \@Component annotations? When you use \@Autowired and \@Component annotations, you make your code depend on Spring. If you define your beans with \@Bean, your Spring configuration is separate from your code. It is not so clean letting your code depend on Spring. Imagine you create a library, then you force users of your library to use the same dependency injection framework while they may already be using another one.

Comment: @rorschach I could remove the component annotation and have that in configuration class itself. But I do not want to remove component annotation as it is autowired in multiple classes.

Comment: Also autowiring does not happen at compile time but at runtime, when the Spring application context is initialized

Comment: @toongeorges I would finally have to do that if i do not get any solution here. The problem is, i have multiple configuration classes and hence i have to rewrite that part in almost all of the configuration classes.

Comment: The arguments you want to autowire need to be defined as beans themselves.  You could define a String Bean with the \@Bean annotation in the configuration class and add a \@Qualifier annotation so you could identify the bean.  You could then wire the bean in the FileU class by using a \@Qualifier annotation with the same identification.

Comment: I think that should do. That's the best I can go, with minimal modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.project")
public class ResponseConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResponseTypeService protectionResponse() throws Exception{
        return new ProtectionTypeResponse();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("fileUInit")
    public String fileUInit() {
        return "whatever";
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class FileU {

    FileWriter fw_output;

    @Autowired
    public FileU(@Qualifier("fileUInit") String s){

    }
}
```

or if that does not work (I have not used the Qualifier annotation on a constructor yet):

```
@Component
public class FileU {

    FileWriter fw_output;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fileUInit")
    private String s;

    public FileU(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from toongeorges will work, however there's a much simpler way by using [@Value annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html). Since you have `fileUnity` in properties file, it's available to spring for autowiring by property name.

See the example below.

```
@Component
public class FileU {

    FileWriter fw_output;

    public FileU(@Value("${fileUnit}") String s){

    }
}
```